# Update a single sqlite row amongst those selected

Tags: python, sqlite

I have a sqlite table that I want to update. I want to change the entry in Col1 on a single row that has Col2 and Col3 taking some specified value.

It is a link table, where many rows have the same combination of elements in  Col2 and Col3. As a result If I run:

```
c.execute("""UPDATE Table1 SET Col1=(?)  
                WHERE Col2=(?) AND Col3=(?)
                """, (var1, var2, var3,))
```

it will cause a problem, because it will change every row where Col2 and Col3 take the specified values.

Notably every row of the table has a unique numerical entry in Col4 - so my intuition is that i could just choose the row with the lowest value in Col4 where Col2 and 3 mach their specified values, but after reading the documentation on UPDATE i am no clearer as how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `Col4` is unique all you have to do is find the row with the min `Col4` where `Col2` and `Col3` are equal to your parameters and you can do it with:

```
SELECT MIN(Col4) FROM Table1 WHERE (Col2, Col3) = (?, ?)
```

So your code should be:

```
c.execute("""UPDATE Table1
             SET Col1 = ?
             WHERE Col4 = (SELECT MIN(Col4) FROM Table1 WHERE (Col2, Col3) = (?, ?)) 
                """, (var1, var2, var3,))
```

Answer (score 1):

You may update using exists logic:

```sql
UPDATE Table1
SET Col1 = ?
WHERE Col2 = ? AND Col3 = ? AND
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Table1 t1
                  WHERE t1.Col2 = Table1.Col2 AND t1.Col3 = Table1.Col3 AND
                        t1.Col4 < Table1.Col4);
```

The exists clause above asserts that for any matching record we cannot find another record with the same `Col2` and `Col3` values but a smaller `Col4` value.